# Subscript range of [UInt8] - Swift

Tags: swift, subscript, uint8array

So the issue I'm having is that I have an object with a argument in the init() that requires an [UInt8]. I want to be able to grab a range from another array and use that in the init. See example.

```
class Test {

    init(fromArray: [UInt8]) {
    // performs work
    }
}

let myStockArray: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] // reference array

let test = Test(fromArray: myStockArray[1...4]) // doesn't work
```

How can I get this to work? The error I get is: Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt8]' with an index of type 'CountableClosedRange'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscripting an array with a range doesn't return an array and  this is the main issue. You are trying to set`ArraySlice<UInt8>` type data to the constructor that have inside `[UInt8]` type.

Try this approach:

```
class Test {

    init(fromArray: [UInt8]) {
        // performs work
    }
}

let myStockArray: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] // reference array

let test = Test(fromArray: Array(myStockArray[1...4]))
```

Comment: Ah that was it. Thanks!